# How to generate this pattern

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, jtextarea

I am totally weak when it comes to looping in Java. And I've got an assignment which asks me to create a pattern generator. The design generator, written in Swing API, asks me to enter a single character and no. of lines I want.

eg. If I enter character x and no. Of lines 6, the output is:

X

XX

XXX

XXXX

XXXXX

XXXXXX

But despite trying it out countless times, it fails to work. And the output has to be displayed in a JTextArea so forget the System.out.println command.
Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: post the code you've written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej,
this code snippet will create a christmas tree, maybe you can adapt it for your needs.

```
    public class Tree {

    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n-i; ++j)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for(int k = 0; k < i*2-1; ++k)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Break this problem down into smaller pieces:

*How do I print n number of X's ?*

```
public void drawLine(int n) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        b.append("X");
    }
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```

*How do I print 1 X, followed by 2 X's, followed by 3 X's....?*

**Hint**: I can use the method I just wrote above, and a for loop.